# SQL use CASE to create new columns

Tags: sql, case

I'm trying to use case statements to split the 'amount' column into two new columns (sum of total rainfall & snowfall) based on the value in 'precipitation_type' to find total rain and snow for a city for a year.

```
select city
  ,(CASE precipitation_type WHEN 'rain' THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS "rainfall"
  ,(CASE precipitation_type WHEN 'snow' THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS "snowfall"
from 
  (select city, precipitation_type, sum(amount) as total
  from precipitation
  group by city, precipitation_type) a
group by city, a.precipitation_type, a.total
order by city asc;
```

My current output looks like this:

```
Albany      0.00    48.51
Baltimore   0.00    0.00
Baltimore   0.00    27.11
Boston      0.00    0.00
Boston      41.12   0.00
Boston      0.00    32.28
```

I want total (sum) of rainfall and snowfall to be in the same record for each city. Ex:

```
Albany       38.54   48.51
Baltimore    40.97   27.11
Boston       41.12   32.28
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

A simple conditional aggregation should return your expected output. Although you did not mentioned your DBMS, this below script should work for you-

```
SELECT city, 
SUM(CASE precipitation_type WHEN 'rain' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS "rainfall",
SUM(CASE precipitation_type WHEN 'snow' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS "snowfall"
FROM precipitation
GROUP BY city
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
select city
  , SUM(CASE precipitation_type WHEN 'rain' THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS rainfall
  , SUM(CASE precipitation_type WHEN 'snow' THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS snowfall
from 
  (select city, precipitation_type, sum(amount) as total
  from precipitation
  group by city, precipitation_type) a
group by city
order by city asc
```

Comment: FYI: I like @mkRabbani 's answer better. Less typing.